# SqlException: Invalid object name 'OpenIddictTokens'

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

When I try to login I get error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'OpenIddictTokens'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__107_0(Task
>   result)
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+d__32.MoveNext()

To confirm things, this is output from output window:

> INSERT INTO [OpenIddictTokens] ([ApplicationId], [AuthorizationId],
>   [Subject], [Type]) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3); SELECT [Id] FROM
>   [OpenIddictTokens] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll

I notice there is not a single OpenIddict table in database. There is a lot of examples where OpenIddictDbContext is used, [but there is a new approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122686/the-type-or-namespace-name-openiddictdbcontext-could-not-be-found) which I use, but something is not working.

My startup file is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    try
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

        services.AddScoped<UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, AppDbContext, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken, AppRoleClaim>, AppUserStore>();
        services.AddScoped<UserManager<AppUser>, AppUserManager>();
        services.AddScoped<RoleManager<AppRole>, AppRoleManager>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<AppUser>, AppSignInManager>();
        services.AddScoped<RoleStore<AppRole, AppDbContext, int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim>, AppRoleStore>();

        var connection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings"];
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer(connection);
            options.UseOpenIddict<int>();
        });

        services
            .AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
            .AddUserStore<AppUserStore>()
            .AddUserManager<AppUserManager>()
            .AddRoleStore<AppRoleStore>()
            .AddRoleManager<AppRoleManager>()
            .AddSignInManager<AppSignInManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddOpenIddict<int>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddMvcBinders()
            .EnableTokenEndpoint("/API/authorization/token")
            .AllowPasswordFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
            .DisableHttpsRequirement();

        services.AddSingleton<DbSeeder>();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DbSeeder dbSeeder)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true
        });
    }
    else
    {

    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIdentity();

    app.UseOpenIddict();

    app.UseOAuthValidation();

    app.UseMvc();

    try
    {

        dbSeeder.SeedAsync();
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

and my DbContext:

```
public partial class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //fix table names
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("Users");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppRole>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("Roles");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserClaim>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("UserClaims");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppRoleClaim>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("RoleClaims");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserRole>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("UserRoles");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserLogin>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("UserLogins");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserToken>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("UserTokens");
        });


        //add our
```

I override all my identity classes (IdentityRole, IdentityRoleClaim, IdentityUser ...) to use `<int>` as TKey.

**I do not know why OpenIdDict tables are not created. I already drop my database, create new and run**

```
dotnet ef migrations add "Initial" -o "Data\Migrations"
dotnet ef database update
```

**, but only identity tables are created.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps (tables are created) if I call `modelBuilder.UseOpenIddict<int>()`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.UseOpenIddict<int>();

    //fix table names
```

Comment: I had to skip the <int> since I use the default Identity models but your answer got me there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your Package Manager Console:

```
add-migration
```

and then

```
update-database
```

it should fix the error

Answer (score 0):

See the connection string in the "startup.cs" class and "appsettings.json" config file. In my case was the name of the instance of SQL Server Express.